# style a div inside a template literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest

i have this `api data` coming from a server and i wanna dynamically render the data based on each response.
problem occurs when i am trying to change the style of the div

say i have this div container with `4 child element`

```html
<div class ='parent'>
      <div id = 'child_1'></div>
      <div id = 'child_2'></div>
      <div id = 'child_3'></div>
      <div id = 'child_4'></div>
    </div>
```

here is the `css`

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(395px, auto);
  height: 100vh;
}
.grand_parent {
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; */
  position: relative;
}

.parent > div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2.3em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is the `js` with just one chunk of data

```js
const data = [59.18, 70.39, 77.8, 60.43, 57.09, 53.59, 47.66, 61.3, 47.64, 55.45, 
43.57, 72.31, 54.03, 63.32, 52.37, 45.14, 53.2, 48.16, 51.13, 45.34];



const dataOne = data[1];
console.log(data);

// childOne.style.width = '60%';


const markup = data.map(el =>{
     return `
  <div class = 'grand_parent'>
  <div class ='parent'>
    <div id = 'child_1' style='width:${el};'></div>
    <div id = 'child_2'></div>
    <div id = 'child_3'></div>
    <div id = 'child_4'></div>
  </div>
</div>
`
}
)

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',markup);
```

i have been trying as much techniques as i have in my newbie vault,here are the ones so far

```js
let childOne = document.getElementById('child_1');
childOne.style.width= `${data}%`;
```

if i do this nothing happens :S

another one to check -

```js
let childOne = document.getElementById('child_1');
childOne.style.width= `${dataOne}%`;
//This only applies to the first div and rests have no idea about this code
```

I am trying to do this with just pure **vanilla Js** here.any other ways to render such progress bar is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: you don't need to make so much efforts you can just add px after of something like this ${el}px

Comment: Yes.i just figured that out that this one unit character is where i messed it all up.Thank you for your time tho.Have a blessed week man! :)

Comment: You are always Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well,basically i could put this as an inline styling like this..

```
<div id = 'child_1' style='width:${el}%;'></div>
```

This one silly missed unit symbol took 2 days out of my project.
but feels good as i was able to learn a great deal trying to figure out things own my own.